# added typelib via makepy for AutoCAD, now win32com not working for AutoCAD

Tags: python, autocad, win32com

I have been running `win32com` to access AutoCAD for quite some time without issue. I learned that applying the `makepy` utility could create a more user friendly experience at the interactive prompt, so I ran it and added the "AutoCAD 2006 Type Library". Now, some common attributes that I used to access are no longer available. Consider the code:

```py
acad = win32com.client("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.Documents.Open('mydoc.dwg')
ms = doc.ModelSpace
count = ms.Count #counts all entities in dwg

for i in range(count):
    item = ms.Item(i)
    if 'block' in item.ObjectName.lower():
        print item.Name
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 462, in 
  __getattr__ raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" 
  (repr(self),attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.AutoCAD 2006 Type Library.IAcadEntity instance 
  at 0x34894552>' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

`Name` has always been an accessible attribute of a block until I ran `makepy`. I've tried reinstalling Python for windows to see if that would reset it, but it didn't work.

**Does makepy create another file upon implementation that I need to remove?**

So many of my scripts depend upon the `Name` attribute. Any suggestions or help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I found a gen_py directory located in a Temp directory which was tied to the issue. After removing the gen_py directory, everything works accordingly again. Guess there is a bug with the api between makepy and AutoCAD?

When I parsed the file that it generated, I saw 'Name' as a property of an acdbBlock/acdbBlockReference class. Not sure why it's not registering when I run my scripts?

Answer (score 3):

The main reason for this attribute error is because your COM-server has shifted from late-binding (dynamic) to early binding (static).

- In Late Binding, whenever a method is called, the object is queried for the method and if it succeeds, then the call can be made.
- In Early Binding, the information of the object model is determined in advance from type information supplied by the object call. Early binding makes use of MakePy. Also, early binding is case sensitive.

There are two ways to fix this issue:

1. Use the dynamic module to force your code to work in a late-bound oriented way. Example use:

   `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch()` instead of `win32com.client.Dispatch()`
2. Use camelcase sensitive keywords for the early bound oriented way. Example use:

   `excel.Visible()` instead of `excel.VISIBLE()` or `excel.visible()`

So try using `dynamic.Dispatch` or case-sensitive variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I no longer work on the network where I was experiencing this issue and do not have access to AutoCAD to test/validate what you're saying. If someone else comments and says that this corrects the specific problem for them, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter a similar problem when I run `win32com` to access DELMIA. I find out that delmia has lots of com stuff as `.tlb` files. When I type:

```py
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
EnsureDispatch('DELMIA.Application')
```

Python will automatically generate some stuff in `win32com\gen_py` directory, same as example of Word or Excel. But, the difference is that the generated stuff is from only one `.tlb` file of delmia. If I access some variable in the `.tlb, it's ok:

```py
docs = delmia.Documents
```

If I access some variable in other `.tlb`, I get a similar error:

```py
pdoc = docs.Add('Process')
```

Python says that:

> ... object has no attribute ...

So I delete all files in the `win32com\gen_py` directory but keep `gen_py` directory, and it is ok now.